# NHibernate dehydration

Tags: nhibernate

Is there a way with NHibernate to take an instance of some mapped type and dehydrate it to an `object[]` that corresponds to the columns of the database if this instance were to be persisted in the database?

Answer (score 1):

it would be helpful to know your use case. Maybe there is a better way to solve it but here goes what you requested:

```
var persistor = session.GetSessionImplementation().GetEntityPersister(obj.GetType().Name, obj);
object[] values = persistor.GetPropertyValues(obj, NHibernate.EntityMode.Poco);
```